# CMD and Powershell work differently for building and running java files

Tags: powershell, java, cmd.exe

See this: [YouTube video reference](https://youtu.be/NBuzlxzo3H0)

Here, cmd works fine when working with Java, but not Powershell. Why is it so and how to make Powershell work with it?

**Update (adding commands and outputs, so you may skip watching the video)**

CMD:

```
C:\Users\reesh\Desktop\Java>javac MyFirstJavaProgram.java

C:\Users\reesh\Desktop\Java>java MyFirstJavaProgram
Hello World

C:\Users\reesh\Desktop\Java>
```

Powershell:

```
PS C:\Users\reesh\Desktop\Java> javac .\MyFirstJavaProgram.java
PS C:\Users\reesh\Desktop\Java> java .\MyFirstJavaProgram
Error: Could not find or load main class .\MyFirstJavaProgram
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /\MyFirstJavaProgram
PS C:\Users\reesh\Desktop\Java>
```

In other words, PS is giving error, while cmd is not.

Comment: It is because powershell works fundamentally different. It would likely be .\javac "MyFirstJavaProgram.java" though

Comment: Thank you. Solved my confusion. I am a newbie and I see people downvoting rather than giving answers. Very hostile.

Comment: Welcome to the internet, the place where some people are not friendly to others because they forget there are real people on the other side of the internet too.

Comment: @Reeshabh by the way it was a good question it cleared my doubt also.

Answer (score 2):

By default, Powershell has a security configuration that when you try to run a program by just giving the name, it does not search the current folder like cmd. Instead it just searches your PATH variable.

Therefore, the first fix is to make `javac` to `./javac`. Secondly, when you write `.\MyFirstJavaProgram`, Java doesn't seem to be able to read the file name. Instead try making it a forward slash `./MyFirstJavaProgram`.

Final command `./java.c ./MyFirstJavaProgram`. Although, I want to emphasise this, you don't need a `./` on MyFirstJavaProgram because it is an argument, not a script or executable.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't run the same command in both.

In the command shell, you ran `java MyFirstJavaProgram`

In PowerShell, you ran `java .\MyFirstJavaProgram`

If you had run the same command it would have worked. It's nothing to do with whether you're running from PowerShell. The issue is that Java expects you to give it the class name. The class name is not `.\MyFirstJavaProgram` - the class name is `MyFirstJavaProgram`.

You get the class name from what you write inside your `.java` file where it says `class MyFirstJavaProgram`.